# insert value to specific index in link list php

Tags: php, linked-list, addition

I want to insert value to specific index in link list($wordsposition) in php.
it trows me the exeption OutOfRangeException so I check my index in my linked list and it looks fine.
it's my first time using linked list in php so I'm probebly doing something wrong but I don't really know what it is.. I would appreciate your help!

here is my code:

```
 $wordsposition = new SplDoublyLinkedList(); 
        foreach ($searchwords as $key => $value) {
            $wordsposition -> push(array($value=>' '));
        }
        print_r($wordsposition);
        echo "<br>";
        foreach ($searchwords as $key => $value) {
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM words WHERE word='$value'";
            $res = $conn->query($sql);

            if ($res->num_rows > 0) {//check if find matching 
                while ($row = $res->fetch_assoc()) {
                   $wordsposition->add($value,$row['num']);
                     echo " my index is: ".$value."<br>";
                     echo " my file is: ".$row['num']."<br>";
                }
            }
        }
```

and here is my echos:

```
SplDoublyLinkedList Object ( [flags:SplDoublyLinkedList:private] => 0 [dllist:SplDoublyLinkedList:private] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [alright] => ) [1] => Array ( [always] => ) [2] => Array ( [around] => ) [3] => Array ( [and] => ) ) ) my index is: alright
my file is: 0
my index is: always
my file is: 2
my index is: always
my file is: 3
my index is: always
my file is: 4
my index is: around
my file is: 0
my index is: around
my file is: 4
my index is: and
my file is: 0
my index is: and
my file is: 1
my index is: and
my file is: 2
my index is: and
my file is: 3
my index is: and
my file is: 4
```